# Configure a tabbar's selected viewcontroller before the view was loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

responding to a specific set of remote notifications, I want the app to open on a certain tab in the tabbar.

in `application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo`

I have

```
 MainTabViewController *tabBarController = (MainTabViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        tabBarController.initialTab = 2;

        MyVC *vc = (MyVC *)tabBarController.selectedViewController;

        [vc doStuff];
```

with `MainTabViewController` is a subclass of `UITabBarController`

and settings the `initalTab` will set the selectedIndex inside viewDidLoad of the `MainTabViewController`

Problem is that on the first time the app opens, the 3rd tab (initialTab = 2) was not instantiated yet, so I can't preconfigure it

How can I either eager load that tab's viewcontroller (so I can access it) or instantiate it myself so I can configure it (and so that the tabbar will continue function properly)

Comment: How does the `initialTab` property work? If you use `selectedIndex` property of `UITabBarController`, it will work.

Comment: What you meant was that the MainTabViewController's initiate routine is not done when notification delegate invoked, you can set a value to check after TabBarController's instantiate done.

Comment: using selectedIndex works, as it will cause the tabbar to switch to the selected controller, which (for me) only works if I already tapped on the tabbar icon and the controller was already instantiated. If the app launches fresh, it won't switch to the new tab

Comment: Check that the rootViewController is nil or not when app launched freshly. I don't think it's a matter of tabBarViewController's viewControllers.